# How can I render a Backbone Collection correctly in a view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I'm trying to learn [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org) and I now used the example on [this page](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/9-collection-views-in-backbone-js-learning-backbone-js/) to create a view from a Collection. For this I use a Collection:

```
var ContactEventCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.id = options.id;
        this.lastContactEventId = options.lastContactEventId;
    },
    url: function() {
        return 'ticket/' + this.id + '/contact-events/' + this.lastContactEventId;
    }
});
```

one view for the conversation and one for the contact event (contact event is basically a message):

```
var ConversationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(contactEvent){
            var contactEventView = new ContactEventView({model: contactEvent});
            this.$el.append(contactEventView.render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

var ContactEventView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#contact-event-template').html()),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

the referenced `#contact-event-template` looks like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="contact-event-template">
    <div class="user-message"><%= text %></div>
</script>
```

I then try to append it to this div (`<div id="put-conversation-here">put the conversation here!</div>`):

```
var contactEventCollection = new ContactEventCollection([], {id: 1, lastContactEventId: 0});
contactEventCollection.fetch();
console.log(contactEventCollection);
var conversationView = new ConversationView({collection: contactEventCollection});
console.log(conversationView);
$('#put-conversation-here').append(conversationView.render().el);
```

In the console I see that conversationView looks like the image below. The weird thing is that I do have a collection, and I do have a view which incorporates all these models, but what gets appended is just an empty: `<div></div>` (not even with the `class="user-message"`).

I also tried replacing `this.model.toJSON()` with a simple object: `{text: "some text"}`, but to no avail. By now I'm totally lost and out for any help I can get. If I could I would immediately put up a bounty for this, but unfortunately I have to wait two days before doing that.

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong here? All help, tips or tricks are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: May be the `contactEventCollection.fetch();` is called async and before data is fetched, your html is getting rendered? You may want to use `$.when(contactEventCollection.fetch()).done(function(){html population});`  But not sure about it.

Comment: @Pushkar - You sir, are simply awesome. That was it, thanks!

Comment: I am not master, just started using it.We use handlebar.js. Pls mark post as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contactEventCollection.fetch();` is called async and before data is fetched, your html is getting rendered.

You may want to use

`$.when(contactEventCollection.fetch()).done(function(){html population});`

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.fetch` is being called async, so your result is not yet there when you try to access it.

The "backbone way" of doing it is to listen to event and make sure your view will do the right thing, no matter what state the collection is at.

Ideally, your view covers the complete life cycle of your collection, so it always represent the current state:

```
var ConversationView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    // add a view when a model is added to the collection.
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addContactEventView);
  },
  render: function () {
    // create views for all existing models
    this.collection.each(addContactEventView, this);
    return this;
  },
  addContactEventView: function (model) {
    var contactEventView = new ContactEventView({model: contactEvent});
    this.$el.append(contactEventView.render().el);
    // remove the view when model destroys.
    contactEventView.listenTo(model, 'remove', contactEventView.remove);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could have a code like this.(code in coffeescript)

//Inside you view.

```
 template ://receive the template html in you case ('#contact-event-template')

initialize:->
    @listOfContact = ''
    @collection = new ContactEventCollection()
    @collection.on 'triggeredEvent', @render, @
    @collcetion.getConversations()


render:->
    @collection.each (model) =>
          @listOfContact += @template(item.toJSON())
    @$el.html(@listOfContact)
```

This way you just have one access to DOM, avoiding go there for every item of your collection, It's more performatic :)